# Can an array in typescript be typed so its items are restricted to only allow shared id's with items in another array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I am building an object with an index signature: `ColumnAndColumnSettings`. I'd like to restrict `columnSettings` to only allow objects with id's shared in `columns`.

```
  type Column = {
  colId: string,
  width?: number,
  sort?: number
  something?: string
}

type ColumnSetting = Pick<Column, 'colId' | 'width' | 'sort'>;

const columnExample = { colId: '1', something: 'test'};
const columnSettingExample1 = { colId: '1'};
const columnSettingExample2 = { colId: '2'};

export const ColumnAndColumnSettings: {
  [key: string]: { columns: Column[]; columnSettings: ColumnSetting[]};
} = {
  people: { columns: [columnExample] , columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1] }, // ok
  boats: { columns:  [columnExample], columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1, columnSettingExample2] }, // ok but want this to error, 
  //columnSettingExample2 does not share id with any item in columns
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=3&pln=18&pc=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeBYAKCigGNEBJAEwC4oBnYAJwEs0BzAGkOIHdnLgACwD8tNKgBGERlyL04jYKKjiUUxt3koIQ1m2UMW7QgF9C5gqEixEqNAGUdwPVigAFZiQDWAHnjJ0DigAcjIEKmCoAB8QvgFBSJjgugVgYIA+AG4LMjQGUlt0AFEADwBDFDAEaGwcAvCaEIBGYKCU7V12WmDgCAZgk2yCXPywu0dgZ3ZSiqqIJtc6sKpulsHCEeB68ac9GcrqgCZF+pWQw4GhwggSsFSCvK3-OwBBNEpn9AmptjpafDkAG0vBAQLRDHoALr-bboP42AJoQGQzKwhy7djwz7oyZ6ZHrAgmRaaSBwOYwsZw2iAylofZzSFQIK0756eE0wo4n706pNRkmIIAekFUDgXk0EjgZWA8KWnPhUA5iJ5EEhzM5rMx1JZGLYKqa6sRmr15QOEEO-KFIrFUAkSC2PDKaC2ujoUGAcCg0kYCiCmmFOtx01Nc2OlDgfRUcC2dEEZUY0H4UD4QigTpAUGYvRQmYwtLopkIQA)

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that behaves this way.  You can write a generic constraint and a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5olm).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Also, please [edit] to put any code necessary to understand the question directly in the question as plaintext... someone shouldn't be required to navigate to the TS Playground to understand the question.

Comment: So, uh, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5olm) work for you or not?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah that solved it, again! I see that helper method actually made it into the generated JS but its sole purpose was to help define the type. Do you recommend anything for further reading on that? The help has been fantastic, thanks!

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I don't know what to say about where to read about the general concept of helper functions in TypeScript.  Other than suggesting you use the word "helper" when searching for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get started: the only way the compiler will even be able to notice the `colId` property values aren't just of type `string` is if you give it some hint that it should be tracking their [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The easiest way to do that is via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when you create the objects:

```
const columnExample = { colId: '1', something: 'test' } as const;
/* const columnExample: {  readonly colId: "1";  readonly something: "test"; } */
const columnSettingExample1 = { colId: '1' } as const;
/* const columnSettingExample1: {  readonly colId: "1"; } */
const columnSettingExample2 = { colId: '2' } as const;
/* const columnSettingExample2: {  readonly colId: "2"; } */
```

Now the compiler knows that `columnExample` has a `colId` of `"1"` instead of `string`, for instance.

Moving on:

---

There is, unfortunately, no specific type in TypeScript that behaves the way you'd like `ColumnAndColumnSettings` to behave.

Instead, you could write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `ColumnAndColumnSettings<T>` where `T` is a mapping from the keys of your object to the set of allowable column ids for that property:

```
type ColumnAndColumnSettings<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    columns: (Column & { colId: T[K] })[],
    columnSettings: (ColumnSetting & { colId: T[K] })[]
  }
}
```

Which results in something like this:

```
type Example = ColumnAndColumnSettings<{ cars: "3" | "4", trucks: "5" }>;
/* type Example = {
    cars: {
        columns: (Column & {
            colId: "3" | "4";
        })[];
        columnSettings: (ColumnSetting & {
            colId: "3" | "4";
        })[];
    };
    trucks: {
        columns: (Column & {
            colId: "5";
        })[];
        columnSettings: (ColumnSetting & {
            colId: "5";
        })[];
    };
} */
```

But you don't want to have to *write out* the particular `T` argument. It would be nice if the compiler could *infer* it for you.  And it can, but not directly via type annotation; you can't do this:

```
const ColumnAndColumnSettings: ColumnAndColumnSettings = { // error!
// --------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cars: { columns: [ce3, ce4], columnSettings: [ce3] },
  trucks: { columns: [ce5], columnSettings: [ce5] },
};
```

There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794) asking for this, and maybe eventually you could write that or something like `ColumnAndColumnSettings<infer>`, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

As I said though, this is possible if you refactor.  The general workaround for cases like this is to create a generic helper identity function whose sole purpose is to infer the type parameter.  That is, instead of `const value: GenericType<infer> = { something: 123 }`, you write a helper function of the form `const asGenericType = <T,>(g: GenericType<T>) => g` and then call it as `const value = asGenericType({something: 123})`.

In this case we'd write

```
const asColumnAndColumnSettings = <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  c: ColumnAndColumnSettings<T>) => c;
```

And now we can use it:

```
const c = asColumnAndColumnSettings({    
  cars: { columns: [ce3, ce4], columnSettings: [ce3] },
  trucks: { columns: [ce5], columnSettings: [ce5] },
});
/* const c: ColumnAndColumnSettings<{
  cars: "3" | "4";
  trucks: "5";
}> */
```

So `T` is inferred as desired. Great!

---

Unfortunately, it's not quite right:

```
const ColumnAndColumnSettings = asColumnAndColumnSettings({
  people: { columns: [columnExample], columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1] }, // ok
  boats: { columns: [columnExample], 
    columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1, columnSettingExample2] }, // no error
});
/* const ColumnAndColumnSettings: ColumnAndColumnSettings<{
  people: "1";
  boats: "1" | "2";
 }> */
```

There's no error in the above, which was the whole point.  The compiler was happy to infer `T` from both the `columns` property *and* the `columnSettings` property.  You really only want to infer `T` from `columns`, and have the compiler *check* the `columnSettings` property against it.

That is, the `T` in the definition of `ColumnAndColumnSettings<T>` inside the `columnSettings` property should be a *non-inferential type parameter usage*.  TypeScript doesn't *directly* support such a feature, and there is a issue in GitHub asking for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  Luckily though, there are workarounds mentioned in there.  The one I'll use here is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the type parameter usage with the empty object type `{}` to lower its inference priority, [as recommended](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731):

```
type ColumnAndColumnSettings<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    columns: (Column & { colId: T[K] })[],
    columnSettings: (ColumnSetting & { colId: T[K] & {} })[]
// ----------------------------------------------> ^^^^
  }
}
```

This acts much the same, and `ColumnAndColumnSettings<{ cars: "3" | "4", trucks: "5" }>` hasn't changed.  But now:

```
const ColumnAndColumnSettings = asColumnAndColumnSettings({
  people: { columns: [columnExample], columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1] }, // ok
  boats: { 
    columns: [columnExample], 
    columnSettings: [columnSettingExample1, columnSettingExample2] }, // error! 
// ---------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Types of property 'colId' are incompatible.
});

// const ColumnAndColumnSettings: ColumnAndColumnSettings<{ people: "1"; boats: "1"; }>
```

We get the error you were looking for!  The entry in `T` for `boats` is just `"1"` instead of `"1" | "2"`, and therefore the `columnSettingExample2` element of the array is flagged as having an incompatible `colId` property.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeBYAKCigGNEBJAEwC4oBnYAJwEs0BzAGkOIHdnLgACwD8tNKgBGERlyL04jYKKjiUUxt3koIQ1m2UMW7QgF9CoSLESo0AZR3A9WKAAVmJANYAeeMnQcoAHIyBCpAqAAfIL4BQXCowLoFYECAPgBuQkIyNAZSa3QAUQAPAEMUMARobBx80JoggEZAgKTtXXZaQOAIBnCTKFK6fNzgTIIAegAqEbyQmxLyyohaWqhGCFLKODQEEDqqWgAiRqP04g2tnb2tHUE9Y56GM6gBqYnsnbmCuwc9RYqVUazlqIUOTX6g2GOQY42ms2AdRs9mAjnYAOWjVWF02212+zBDROLzeHwIMMR83QKLRbAxVQATCCDg1AgzIUMEXCZhSkdS-uiyoCIAzsetcdcCRQiQySVB3lkCIrCGhyr0wKUSNAAGLMRgMAAqjH2+CVcgs0F8NgAgmhKFb+ai9HQvAaoBBij07cMAEoQMiMSheDwQEBwABmUANrSYelSqRBmmIAG0ANJQVhQENhyMGgC6qyTxD5uVoAAoHRgAGS4Fm0A1pvOvACUybzsmLxapvyd7Do5crNKcNdB0vrjZbbaLZjkM80Fqg9OqVj8aFt9p+Q77XlBpX1xwAzEdIlAjgAWI4BJhITz908AVmPJgymnhC6XibknZIe7vps7AElneFY-FAI5FoB35jqeR4nueZwQQBJitnm4yQV2m4CmwwGDlhYG4Ih6GEoex5RPBaHoZOqGISYFGdtet6Fl+kHdjhoHgcxlF1g+CGcUhKF0SxmG9thA7CbS+H-lxGH1Mcj6CYByFtgprwUaSirELyQyVuuuEicM2Cuu6noQN6UB+gGQbZhGUYxkYbDxmWRYkLQOl2nptIugaqTNlgCYkOMmi8lqB7MsRQQHi0twdGwXRPCkrxQlyQVfJSEBnmF0GBGeUVtHcDxBPFHLQqlFHBRA96ZbJQT3rlcDtPcnSFb0CUDJyFKBXIwXONpPy6eJzpllJmm-tirG0MmIUBFqZ7tiWW6iVAk0QAeTYmB2xYMR4f5ARNWr3nN3YLXey0Ha8G3IRR8LBa5fXuQN27DaQo0waRp4XoJW13kc8maM+8pkhpCIrja92rsdPV0G5G7g1hdBDUWkBwMsY0-Cd3ZLodD2LZN2NLo0a0BBMExQHAHhFhIcClMAO3jUtGNCssWOw-pe144zQLTezSyMoTUDEyocDuowjAKH9zZXTyqUg+g-Us55t2rnLyJwzuiMQMjVTHKcgmU9T32nHBsp0f9CpmqYiqqtodAalqUD2DklBGiaQMLtDHnOkZHpepQvr+goVmhjZ0b0LG7Dxp+nZphmGDWbmBYEXxdMgaukncQ2qZrShG1QfLzpiXn7Bp+FGdNiOAxKXm05-a74DQB+2Du9jLq7vur1wReV6MDe21yU+L5yG+deLhzy5PSNbfjwByeVpJhFCdVRywWRH3z8QlcqbnKus1AKfbxJHHSTJ4JL295Fr1RKm0YhX1MVxM-sYnR+adBP28VxG8X0dcMF-vw5P8-cKb9N7Fk-nxa+s4AbKjNC-UYUIm6F2ws4L2JkzIWQDsGIOuY7JxlSE5ZiLkZZrjBn-bc3lfKYH8p1WBcwVpVXBIESKrR6r5Sat0FqxVkpdWljNehrIcrMIagVdhfRErtVKilOB+0+FdFqoI1hsVmqiLaiVUY1DgYkEhgg0h2EEYEJeqOVc6MVrTXSszHRxjVrnSLLfWsdNTrmMdAremFVCbi0lhoxWoMYYWLVvotup8O7v02t3RiPE1IJjNkDXk2inHOi0XdHxcS+x6M7EjFGdi0Zs1XJjLmiD0bc2FATc6-MSZkwplTGmqMjHZIWKPRxPZnG40QfjPJOilwMj5gLaQotGAAEIox12GDZMAotICKH2MEaU4Q9zQFYGQCo1NmASCqAAOnca+EmMTEkez7F42WJDknYR3FAdJWtTw6ygHrKpFySSpEVDOIAA)